# Getting cors error while downloading the image from presigned URL in react js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I get this error when trying to download the image from presigned URL

Access to fetch at 'https://unikphotography-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/48494c71-2417-4a63-99c2-d3279f8becce_.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXRK6DUIY6DI4FSOM%2F20231229%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231229T203002Z&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Signature=b98f4ca4485f73061cc28643fdee99d77dd37a729bfcfd1b3e1c714f1fcd6f88&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have updated cors policies in s3 as per following

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3000",
>!             "other domains"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

The Video file is getting downloaded, the problem is with image file.

below is the react code

```
const handleDownload = async (imageURL) => {
    setisLoading(true)
    console.log(imageURL,'+',auth.token)
    try {

      const response = await fetch(imageURL,{
        header:{
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        }
      });
      
        if(response.ok){
         console.log('ok')
          const blob = await response.blob();
          console.log(blob)
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = 'unik-photograhy-image';
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
     
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error downloading image:', error);
    }finally{
      setisLoading(false)
    }
  };
```

I tried updating the cors policy to allow all the origins, making the s3 bucket access to public.

Comment: Can you remove the >!             "other domains" part from your policy and try again

Comment: Yes I did, it's not working.

Comment: How are you authenticating that the incoming request is a legit one or not?
Any sort of authentication and authorization using the IAM user's access and secret keys? I am asking this because I do not see it in your code. Also, ensure that your S3 bucket's policy is allowing the specified origin to fetch resources from the bucket.

Comment: Yes, we're using secret key to authenticate.

Comment: Change the header to headers in the fetch section. I think that should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following piece of code, you should try changing **header** to **headers**

Also, check whether the image that you are trying to download is in JPEG or any other format because in the headers we are specifying the Content-Type as image/jpeg but if the requested image format is different then also the code may throw an error

```
const handleDownload = async (imageURL) => {
  setisLoading(true);
  console.log(imageURL, "+", auth.token);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(imageURL, {
      // Change header to headers here
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
      },
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("ok");
      const blob = await response.blob();
      console.log(blob);

      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "unik-photography-image";
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error downloading image:", error);
  } finally {
    setisLoading(false);
  }
};
```

Comment: this piece of code is working fine for downloading video, the only problem is with the images

Comment: okay, so the problem is when I disabled the cache in devtools, the images are getting downloaded.

Comment: Okay, seems you got the problem :)